# Is it possible to export animated 3D graphics objects for VR viewing?

Tags: graphics3d, export

I'd like to take an animated 3D graphics object (perhaps created using Animate] and export it to something like [sketchfab](http://sketchfab.com) for VR viewing with Google Cardboard.  Sketchfab requires either FBX or BLEND formats.  Is there a way to convert a format Mathematica can export into one of those formats?

Comment: If we cross-reference the supported file formats in *Mathematica* [3D exporting](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/3DGeometryAndModelingFormats.html) with the [one from sketchfab](https://help.sketchfab.com/hc/en-us/articles/202508396-3D-File-Formats), there should be a satisfactory intersection right?

Comment: Sketchfab only takes FBX and BLEND files for animations.  I can import static 3D models with no trouble.

Comment: Correct, I missed the difference between an animation and a static model. I guess in this case your best bet would be to export a movie from *Mathematica*, then import it using e. g. Blender and use that to export a .blend / .fbx animation.